# Reusable component UITableView datasource for multiple screen with same structure in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, code-reuse

[image]

I have 3 screens that contain almost the same display for UITableView and cells. All the three screen have same table structure but model type is different for all screens.

I can do that but I have to repeat the same code for tableview in all screens: (cellforRow, Number, data, and calculations...)

what is the best approach to avoid duplicating data in such a case?

Comment: Can you show how your model classes so we know how they are similar? Also show how they are displayed in table view cells.

Comment: I understand your scenario. This can be easily achieved by subclassing from parent that will implement tableViews method and the child that will only set the source. If given more context and some source we could point you in right direction

Comment: Table view have collapsable section for example there are two sections "A" and "B". All Screens have same UITableView with two or more collapsible sections. Model objects for screens have same structure but model objects are different.

Comment: "TestJson": {
  "A": "12",
  "Name": "test 1",
  "CollapseSections": [
   {
    "SectionType": "A",
    "Name": "A",
    "SectionInfos": [
     {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "row1"
     },
     {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "row 2"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "SectionType": "B",
    "Name": "B",
    "MonitorGroupInfos": [
     {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "row 1"
     },
     {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "2 "
     }
    ]
   },